# Convert only french accents to percent encoding

Tags: java, url, encoding

I need to post a json on an API but where are some problems with a french accent. I need to convert only french accent in my Json. For example, I have:

```
URLEncoder.encode("[{"PARTI_ORIGINE":"Venu pour la journée depuis votre domocile"}]","UTF-8")
```

But I have got this :

```
%5B%0A%7B%22PARTI_ORIGINE%22%3A%22Venu+pour+la+journ%C3%A9e+depuis+votre+domicile%22%0A%7D%5D
```

and I need this result :

```
[{"PARTI_ORIGINE":"Venu pour la journ%C3%A9e depuis votre domocile"}]
```

Can you help me please ?
Of course I could write my own function, but it is faster and I risk less errors if there is already a method.

Have a nice day.

Comment: What about: `"[{\"PARTI_ORIGINE\":\"" + URLEncoder.encode("Venu pour la journée depuis votre domocile","UTF-8") + "\"}]"`?

Comment: I think I have to test if I can separate these two parts in a sustainable way, but I will test. Thank you very much, I just did not think.